# How to determine if you're connected via wifi or ethernet on Ubuntu Server?

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, internet, ethernet

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu Server 20.04.1 on a Raspberry Pi 3 B+

I initially set it up connected via WiFi. I now plugged in an ethernet cable but I'm unsure how to tell which is currently the active connection via the command line. I'd prefer to disable the WiFi and have a wired connection.

I'd also like to know how to re-enable WiFi in the future in case I ever disconnect the cable.

I ran ifconfig -a and see the output for both eth0 and wlan0

Comment: Please edit Your question and add output of the command `ifconfig -a`. The interface currently being used should have `UP,RUNNING` in the flags section of the output.

Comment: Both eth0 and wlan0 show UP,RUNNING in the flags section.

Comment: Edited to include the ifconfig output

Comment: Try `route` command and see which interface is marked as `default` [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14961/how-to-find-out-which-interface-am-i-using-for-connecting-to-the-internet).

Comment: Ahh thanks for that command. It's eth0. I also added an answer for a solution using network-manager.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I found a solution. I installed network-manager via apt and ran:

```
nmcli radio wifi off
```

And to turn back on:

```
nmcli radio wifi on
```

Comment: This seems to answer your secondary question, not the question's title of how to determine whether ethernet or wifi? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since both wired and WiFi can be connected at the same time, you should ask the system which one it's sending packets through with

```
ip route
```

Read `man ip ip-route`.

Comment: do you mind giving a bit more context on the output of `ip route`? Which part is determinant to answer the question of whether on eth or wifi? Thanks!

Comment: Read https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=131034&seqNum=5 the section on "Subnetting" should explain it.